# Link two html pages ( java script)

Tags: javascript, html, uri

I have two pages. One is index.html and the other is pk_canonical.html. I want to link the pk-canonical.html page with the index page as one of the option in a drop down list. When I tried running the pages. Both the pages are running fine separately, but when I select the option from the drop down list in index page, it says," The server has not found anything matching the requested URI ".and its not going to pk_canonical page.Kindly help me where I went wrong. Below is the code.

index.html:

```
<div class="content">
    <!--<p>-->
        <!--<select data-bind="options: Algorithms,-->
                       <!--optionsText: 'algoName',-->
                       <!--value: selectedAlgorithm,-->
                       <!--optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>-->
    <!--</p>-->

    <!--<div data-bind="visible: selectedAlgorithm"> &lt;!&ndash; Appears when you select something &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--You have chosen a country with population-->
        <!--<span data-bind="text: selectedAlgorithm ? selectedAlgorithm.algoPage : 'unknown'"></span>.-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <select id="algoSelect" onchange="algoSel(this)">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an algorithm</option>
        <option value="Nussinov.html">Nussinov - max. #bp structure</option>
        <option value="counting.html">Structure Counting</option>
        <option value="McCaskill.html">McCaskill - structure probabilities</option>
        <option value="MEA.html">MEA structure</option>
        <option value="co-folding.html">Co-folding interactions</option>
        <option value="hybrid-only.html">hybrid-only interactions</option>
        <option value="accessibility.html">accessibility-based interactions</option>
        <option value="pk_canonical.html">canonical pseudoknot</option>


    </select>

    <div id="algopage">

    </div>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        function loadPage(){
            console.log("algo selected:", document.location);
            var $_GET = {};

            document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
                function decode(s) {
                    return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
                }

                $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
            });

//            console.log($_GET['id']);
            $(algopage).load($_GET['id']);
//            console.log("algo loaded");

        };

        function algoSel(algo){
            window.location='index.html?id=' + algo.value;

        };

    </script>

</div>


</body>
```

pk_canonical.html:

```
 <div class="row" id="introduction">
   <div class="colW600">
     The algorithm by
     <a href="https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkm258">Reeder&Giegerich</a>
     briefly sketch the way to implement  an extension of the usual dynamic programming (DP) scheme for RNA folding [5,6].
     <br />
     Helical stem called 'Canonical stem' which comprises only canonical Watson-Crick base pairs and usually ends with two canonical C=G base pairs before the internal loop.
     C(i,j) =  Maximal length of canonical stem with outermost base pairs (i,j)

     <br />
     A canonical pseudoknot consists of two crossing canonical stems.
     <br />
     The (suboptimal) backtrace procedure the pseudoknot matrix is handled at the end.
     <br />
     <br />
     Here, Since only two helices participate in one pseudoknot, we loop over all possible knots in one O(n4) loop and store the result in a two-dimensional matrix. 
     Finally, the traceback is visualized. 
   </div>
   <div class="colW150">
    <img alt="Canonical pseudoknot" src="output-onlinejpgtools.png" width=120 height=90 >
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your function with this,

```
 function algoSel(algo){
     window.location= algo.value;
 };
```

Hello, so the little problem came from your algoSel(algo) function, just assign the value algo.value to the window.location to enable it redirect to your pk_canonical algorithm page. Thank you.

here,

```
    function algoSel(algo){
        window.location='index.html?id=' + algo.value;
    }
```

,you told js to redirect to your index.html page and look for a resource/path called  pk_canonical.html, instead of telling it to just redirect to pk_canonical.html

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution. But it is not working still. it says pk_canonical.html' not allowed to load. Access is denied.

Comment: hi..sorry..browser wasnt supporting. now its working fine. thank you

Comment: actually, the Microsoft edge is not supporting the pk_canonical page but it supports all the other html pages. In opera and chrome, it supports pk_canonical page but is is not supporting all the other pages.

Comment: As, all the other algorithms are supported in edge, could u please let me know why pk_canonical alone is not supporting

Comment: how can i get the files to test on my own localhost

Comment: i will upload the code in github and will share u the link. is that fine

Comment: the problem is page is loading but not the content of the page.

Comment: i have just shared the link. kindly let me know if u require any help in understanding the files

Comment: after changing your algo function in your index.hmtl to the one written above, it worked fine on all my browsers

Comment: did u select the canonical pseduknot from the drop down list in microsoft edge. its not working..i just tried again

Comment: can you show me the url that is being displayed on your browsers header?, and yes, i selected the canonical pseduknot and it displayed on microsoft edge

Comment: file:///C:/Users/yogapriya/Documents/project/RNA-Playground-master/RNA-Playground-master/index.html
---- after selecting the canonical pseduknot from drop down list, this is the url it shows

Comment: sorry, it still worked, can you show me the url it displays when you select canonical ?

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/priya/project-master/index.html?id=pk_canonical.html , did you get a url similar to this?

Comment: i find it strange..its till not wokring.. it not even showing me the right url..even after selecting canonical pseduknot, it still shows the same url as index

Comment: file:///C:/Users/yogapriya/Documents/project/RNA-Playground-master/RNA-Playground-master/index.html?id=pk_canonical.html
i got when i used the  window.location='index.html?id=' + algo.value;

Comment: okay, can you change the algo function to window.location = algo.value ? then try it out again

Comment: function algoSel(algo){
     window.location= algo.value;
 };                                      this is what you have asked me to do right

Comment: that is what i m trying since long..but its not working it says  : SEC7134: Resource 'file:///C:/Users/yogapriya/Documents/project/RNA-Playground-master/RNA-Playground-master/pk_canonical.html' not allowed to load.

 SCRIPT5: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/066767a5-f9d5-45f4-95cf-dcd0ff030090/quotscript5-access-is-deniedquot-error-when-accessing-web-sites-using-localstorage?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and let u know

Comment: Hey hi, I require your help with my javascript code